# Variable defined with a '.' in the name

Tags: javascript, webpack

Today I noticed something weird while using webpack and the `DefinePlugin`.

Lets say my `webpack.config.js` contains the following:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'foo.bar': JSON.stringify('hello world'),
    'baz': JSON.stringify({bar: 'I am in baz.bar'}),
})
```

And my `global-environment.ts`:

```
declare var foo: object
declare var baz: object
```

Now, I do this on my main script file:

```
console.log(foo.bar)     // hello world
console.log(foo['bar'])  // hello world
console.log(baz.bar)     // I am in baz.bar
console.log(baz['bar'])  // I am in baz.bar
```

And it works fine, but now the fun begins:

```
console.log(foo)  // ReferenceError: foo is not defined
console.log(baz)  // { bar: 15 }
```

Why does it think that `foo` is not defined but I can indeed access `bar` through `.` and `[]`?

My initial suspicion was that it was something similar to when one uses an object as key for another object and it coerces to a string:

```
const a = {}
const b = {}
const b[a] = 15  // {'[object Object]': 15}
```

So `foo.bar` would be equivalent to something like `globals['foo.bar']`, and then it would make sense that `foo` alone be undefined and `foo[bar]` too. Except it isn't, and as mentioned above you can use `foo.bar` and `foo['bar']` normally just as if `foo` was a regular object.

What is happening here?

Comment: `console.log(baz.bar)     // I am in baz.bar` vs `console.log(baz.bar)  // [Object object]` You have the exact same statement returning different things which makes one wonder if we're seeking the whole story.

Comment: It would be easy enough to inspect the bundled source and see what code Webpack is actually emitting.

Comment: @Mark_M Sorry, I meant `console.log(baz)` instead of `console.log(baz.bar)`